# Wordpress custom archive page

Tags: wp-query, query

I am trying to build up a custom archive page. However, I would like this archive page to skip the first 5 posts.

I've been able to accomplish this with the offset property. However, the pagination seems to break.

Here's my code before the while:

```
 <?php
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 $wp_query = new WP_Query();
 $wp_query->query('posts_per_page='.get_option('posts_per_page').'&paged=' . $paged);
 ?>
```

And this is the code I'm using for the pagination:

```
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<div class="nav-previous" style="margin-bottom:24px; font-size:1.3em;"><?php next_posts_link(__('<span class="meta-nav">&laquo;</span> Entradas anteriores', '')) ?></div>
<div class="nav-next" style="margin-bottom:24px; font-size:1.3em;"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Entradas recientes <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>', '')) ?></div>
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Johann

Answer (score 4):

Of course it breaks. Pagination depends on the main query saved in the `$wp_query` object and you have overwritten that. When the next page load the ordinary `wp_query` that you have not overwritten will run and it won't match the one you've altered.

Create a filter for `pre_get_posts` to alter the main query.

```
function pregp_wpse_97354($qry) {
  // control where this runs
  if (is_main_query() && $qry->is_archive()) {
    $qry->set('offset',5);
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','pregp_wpse_97354');
```

Notice `// control where this runs`. The line immediately following determines where this filter runs. I'd don't enough about your setup to get that right so I made something up. *I am sure* that that needs to be more specific.